# Vscode terminal doesnt display folder and branch

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

Following is how I see the termial:

[image]

Vscode for some reason does not display the folder name and git branch by default. I have vscode on another system with no custom settings made and it displays them plus the colours as well.

vscode settings:

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Monokai Dimmed",
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "terminal.integrated.copyOnSelection": true,
    "terminal.integrated.cursorBlinking": true,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The folder name and branch in the terminal prompt come from the shell, not from VS Code.

It is likely that one of your system's shells has a custom prompt set while the other does not. You should also see this when using the system terminal. The solution is to configure the prompt on both systems to be the same

You can also try [configuring the shell that VS Code uses](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_configuration) to ensure VS Code's integrated terminal uses the correct shell with the correct environment

Comment: It was my .bashrc that had something in it. I was able to restore it to a previous version and it fixed the issue.