# How do I show up the current branch in WSL ( I use Vscode)

Tags: bash, git, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I use Vscode, and I want to know Where my HEAD is pointing branch, 
How Can I show up the current branch name like Bash? 
I use WSL(ubuntu)termimal in my Vscode and OS is Windows 10

Thank you

[image: WSL image]

Comment: you can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62514097/show-current-branch-on-terminal

Comment: I've tried your link, but I think it somewhat different, it didn't work for me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that, from [`microsoft/vscode` issue 67670](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/67670), the current branch name is already visible in the status bar of VSCode.

[image: branch VSCode]

Or, [with Git 2.22+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55088865/6309) (Q2 2019)

```
git branch --show-current
```

It is true the [prompt in a git bash in VSCode does not display the Git branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52195777/6309).

You need to [configure the `$SHELL`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_configuration)

> For example, to enable running bash as a login shell (which runs `.bash_profile`), pass in the `-l` argument (with double quotes):

```
// Linux
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.linux": ["-l"]
```

Then in your `~/.bashrc` can [include a special prompt](https://gist.github.com/justintv/168835).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want to know exact way what I said in my question. because I think it's more intuitive and bettter. best regards

Comment: @stefancho I agree. That is why I added to the answer `git branch --show-current`, which is answering your original question

Comment: sorry for my poor question I think it was not well explained, what I want is that to know everytime, like bash. but git branch --show-current is only showing one time.

Comment: @stefancho THank you: this is clearer. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

I got it configured by modifying the .bashrc file in the /home/ on the WSL session. You can do vim ~/.bashrc to edit the file.

Find and replace the code block in the .bashrc with this;

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
        PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\$(`git branch --show-current 2>/dev/null`)\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
        PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$(`git branch --show-current 2>/dev/null`)\$ '
fi
```

Comment: @Digantto Paul It's now  not showing the directory iself more

Answer (score 3):

I found @Diganto Paul's answer does not show the current directory (as it was by default). I used this instead:

```
parse_git_branch() {
   git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\[\033[33m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

Copied from: https://hinty.io/ivictbor/show-git-branch-in-bash-on-linux-windows-wsl-2-cygwin-prompt/